# Replace characters in string on wordpress zapier site

Tags: javascript, string, replace, character, zapier

I have a WordPress website with "code by zapier". I have the string `"||Option 1||Option 3||"`. I need delete the first `"||"` and replace the other `"||"` with `", "`.

It's my first time with Javascript, and I've absolutely no idea how it works. I read about regex online, but I don't know how it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `split` function of `Array` and `shift` for remove first element, after then `join` `Array` with `", "`

You can use `splice` in replace of `shift`

```
valueArray.splice(0,1);
```

where 0 is current `index` and 1 is number of item you want to remove(in your case It is first which means 0)

```js
var string = "||Option 1||Option 3||";
var valueArray = string.split("||");
valueArray.shift();
var resultString = valueArray.join(", ");

console.log(resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks i read the doc and they work !!

```
var valueArray = inputData.change.split("||");
valueArray.shift()
var resultString = valueArray.join(", ")

console.log(resultString);
output = [{'Change': resultString}];
```

the only problem is the last ",", ill try to correct this
thanks !

inputeData is the params, and zapier wait "output" at the end.
i forget use output that why the code wast work.

now is good, he found "Option 1, Option 3, "
ill try delete the last " ,"

he can be "Option 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., option 50,"
I need delete the last

Comment: See my answer if you need to remove the last `,` as well .

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shortest way, using `slice` and `replace` together with regular expression.

```js
const str = "||Option 1||Option 3||";

console.log(str.slice(2).replace(/\|\|/g, ', '));
```

And if you need to remove the last `,` then you can slice it again.

```js
const str = "||Option 1||Option 3||";

const newStr = str.slice(2).replace(/\|\|/g, ', ');

console.log(newStr.slice(0, newStr.length - 2));
```

Comment: i know ur code work but on zapier ive the error "newStr.slice" isnt a function ahahah

Comment: @AdrienHanot If you do `console.log(String.prototype.slice)` what does it print?

Comment: its okey htey work, i forget the "change" at the line : var newStr = inputData.change.slice(2).replace(/\|\|/g, ', ');

Answer (score 0):

it's okey the thead is done i got the solution for use "console.log"

is my first time with zapier wasnt easy, really

the solution :

```
const str = inputData.change;

const newStr = str.slice(2).replace(/\|\|/g, ', ');
console.log(newStr.slice(0, newStr.length - 2));
output = [{'change': newStr.slice(0, newStr.length - 2)}];
```